# Single selection on check box in recycler view with multiple filter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello i am facing this issue, I am implementing the filters of ecommerce App. Where i have below filters

```
Size    - multiple selection with checkbox   (Working fine)
Brand   - multiple selection with checkbox   (Working fine)
Price   - Single selection   with checkbox    (Not working)
```

For Price filter i want to select one price at a time but it's selecting multiple selection, I want if user selects one price range  an shifted to another price range i must be unselect previous price range.
Below is my code:-

````
    public class FilterValAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterValAdapter.ValueViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<FilterMultiple> filterModels;
    private final int resource;
    private final int type;
    private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public FilterValAdapter(Context context, int filter_list_val_row, ArrayList<FilterMultiple> filterModels, int type) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filterModels = filterModels;
        this.resource = filter_list_val_row;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ValueViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(this.context)
                .inflate(resource, viewGroup, false);
        return new ValueViewHolder(v, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ValueViewHolder holder, int i) {
        if (type != 2) holder.subCategoryName.setText(filterModels.get(i).getName());
        else {
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(filterModels.get(i).getName()));
        }
        holder.cbSelected.setChecked(filterModels.get(i).isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filterModels.size();
    }

    public void setItemSelected(int position) {
        if (position != -1) {
            filterModels.get(position).setChecked(!filterModels.get(position).isChecked());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public class ValueViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView subCategoryName;
        private View view;
        private CheckBox cbSelected;

        ValueViewHolder(View itemView, int type) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            subCategoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_list_title);
            view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colored_bar);
            cbSelected = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbSelected);
            if (type != 2) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearName).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else {
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearName).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearColored).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
    ```
I have used two Recycler View One is for Prent one fo child. information below:-

    Suppose **Size** is Parent Recycler view and its child recycler view value is S,M,L

   [Image1][1]
   [Image2][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byaFU.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npywT.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

Add your checkboxes inside a layout and then on click of each check box, loop through all children of the layout and setChecked(false) for other checkboxes.

Example -

In xml-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb0to100"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0 to 100"
    android:onClick="deSelectOthers"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb100to200"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="100 to 200"
    android:onClick="deSelectOthers"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb200to300"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="200 to 300"
    android:onClick="deSelectOthers"/>
```

Java code -

```
public void deSelectOthers(View view) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    for(int i=0; i<linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
        CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(checkBox.getId() != view.getId()){
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you now.

Comment: hello saahil thanks for answer, but i want check box it is requirement.

Comment: I have updated the code for check boxes now bishal.

Comment: i add data in recycler view with list, these are not static, please check the code of bindViewHolder you will understand my checkbox selection is out side of if else, it same for all, i want this same, but need selection single for price range, 
check the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/npywT.jpg

this values are dynamic and populate the recycler view according header like brand, this data is diff

Comment: From the code which I understood, are you storing the status of checkbox in FilterMultiple object?

Comment: exactly saahil, coz it is necessary to hold the value of selected items. all things working fine but just select single value on price filter.